# MongoDB Query Timeout when using references

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a Class A. This class has a field List, which contains a list of other objects of the same type. When referencing this field and trying to query A, the application freezes and causes a TimeoutException. Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here yet to assist. What does "referencing this field" mean? What is the timeout set to? What are sample documents and what is the actual query (both in Morphia and that MongoDB receives)? Do other queries work?